# Comparacion de fechas , actual y una personalidadada

Tags: php, condiciones

Tengo una duda con las fechas en php, estoy haciendo un programa que bloque un botón al llegar una hora y estoy haciendo pruebas con código de pruebas.

Mi duda reside al comparar una fecha creadas con función date

```
//Creo la fecha actual y la hora actual
$day = date("Y-m-d");
echo $fecha_actual= date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Y una fecha del dia de hoy y la hora personalizada

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$date = date_create("20:00:00");
$fecha = date_format($date,"Y/m/d H:i:s");
```

El problema es que al compararla con la fecha actual y es superior por ejemplo ahora es 19:30:00 y la fecha personalizada es a las 20:00:00. La salida es fecha actual es superior que la bloqueada y no bloquea el boton.

```
// hago una comparacion , si la fecha de actual supera, el dia de hoy a la 18:00:00 passara la fecha el dia siguiente si no , no passara  se quedara en la actual
$date 1 es
//Creo el paramentro para sumar + 1 dia si la fecha de maxima supera la actual
$date1=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($day."+ 1 days")); 
if($fecha_actual<$fecha){

    echo "La fecha actual ".$date1;
}else{

    echo "Lo siento la fecha no corresponde para sumar 1 dia";
}
```

Comment: Por favor pon un ejemplo verificable. Qué es date1?

Comment: Perdon ja le puesto date 1 es fecha que le sumo 1 dia //Creo el paramentro para sumar + 1 dia si la fecha de maxima supera la actual
$date1=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($day."+ 1 days"));

Answer (score 1):

lo que pasa es que para comparar fechas en php debes asegurarte que tengan el mismo formato.

te dejo una publicacion que ejemplifica esto y esplica como comparar correctamente usando funciones para generar objetos tipo fecha
ej:

```
<?php 
// PHP program to compare dates 
  
// Declare two dates in different 
// format 
$date1 = "12-03-26"; 
$date2 = "2011-10-24"; 
  
// Use strtotime() function to convert 
// date into dateTimestamp 
$dateTimestamp1 = strtotime($date1); 
$dateTimestamp2 = strtotime($date2); 
  
// Compare the timestamp date  
if ($dateTimestamp1 > $dateTimestamp2) 
    echo "$date1 is latest than $date2"; 
else
    echo "$date1 is older than $date2"; 
  
?>
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comparing-two-dates-in-php/